# Infraestrutura de web API

Tags: restful, asp.net-web-api

Estou construindo um layout de infraestrutura de API's e gostaria de ver as opniões de vocês, bem como ideias de escalabilidade e conceitos aplicados.

Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes de infraestrutura interna, comportamentos e funcionalidades.

Atualmente o layout para o projeto consiste na imagem abaixo:

[image: layout_1]

O projeto possui um sistema heterogêneo que necessita de outras API's para funcionar. Todas agem em conjunto, tornando o acesso totalmente transparente para usuários. Na maioria das vezes as API's possuem dados replicados para validações de consultas no banco de dados.
Ao todo são 4 API's separadas, cada API foi dedicada a fazer operações em específico:

```
API 1 - Moderação

    * Roda em conjunto uma interface WEB construída em Laravel para moderação de dados enviados dos dispositivos mobile e outras plataformas
    * Integra dados na API 2
    * Recebe requisições de dispositivos e outras plataformas
    * Recebe status de pagamentos de API's de terceiros
    * Envia imagens para API 4

API 2 - Integração

    * Recebe dados moderados da API 1
    * Recebe requisições de dispositivos mobile
    * Integra alguns dados necessários para API 3

API 3 - Processamento de dados e gerenciamento

    * Recebe dados da API 2
    * Processa informações a nível de Scripts
    * Recebe requisições de dispositivos mobile

API 4 - Gerenciamento de imagens

    * Recebe imagens da API 1
    * Retorna imagens para dispositivos e outras plataformas
```

Como se trata de um enorme processamento de dados, foi pensado em uma estrutura não central para suprir as necessidades de demannda de disponibilidade dos serviços,
primeiramente foi pensado no layout apresentado na imagem acima onde é possível realizar a integração em paralelo entre as API's e balancear tanto o processamento de dados quanto o acesso aos servidores que hospedam as API's.

Logo, tenho dúvidas referentes a manutenção do código e também na aplicabilidade dessa ideia e gostaria de saber se posso seguir dessa forma, se estou no caminho certo e se realmente é viável seguir essa configuração.
Adotei essa ideia pensando em um número realmente alto de acessos, considerando disponibilidade dos serviços envolvidos onde se um parar, o sistema não para por completo.

Mas tenho visto muitas ideias referente a colocar toda essa estrutura a rodar em um único servidor com uma única API.

Também gostaria de frisar que pretendo iniciar com servidores da Digital Ocean e se os mesmos suportariam uma quantidade simultânea de grandes acessos.

Tecnologias utilizadas:

**PostgreSQL**

- Todas as consultas, updates e inserts rodam a nível de banco de dados
  onde foram criadas funções para esse fim
- O php fica apenas encarregado de realizar o call para as funções.

**Laravel**

- Roda o painel de moderação web
- Roda api

**phpSlim Framework (php7)**

- Roda as demais API's

Comment: Isso tem cara de ser microserviços. Fiquei na dúvida de porquê uma API de integração deve responder às requisições de dispositivos móveis, sendo que há uma API exclusiva para a moderação dos dados?

Comment: Olá amigo, a api de integrações irá trabalhar com um fluxo de dados mais pontual a fim de diminuir a carga de processamento da api de moderação. Resumindo, os dados enviados para os dispositivos estarão "mastigados".